# I have a H07RN-F 3G cable which is rated at 400V/16A, can it be used for a normal 220V schuko connection without consequences?

Tags: power, cables, cable-assemblies

Basically making it a 2.5mm gauge cable, will it have any negative effects on appliances that run on 220V - I am not sure if a 400V/16A rating is the max or the supposed to be used at/for rating?

Comment: Sure you can. No problem if you use lower voltage, the rated current remains the same - 16A for 2.5mm^2.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Voltage and current ratings on cables are always maximum ratings. You can freely use the cable for any current and voltage below its rated values.

Comment: is there anything else I should know about the standards? For example I also see H05RR-F but also H05VV-F, I see that the H05VV-F. How do I choose between them if I don't count the pure Volts, is there any other specifications I should look after? For example if I am having a extension cable for heavy appliance like Oil radiator should the cable be thicker then the appliance itself?

Comment: Other considerations when buying a cable are whether it needs to be water-resistant or oil-resistant, whether it needs to be armored, whether it needs to be shielded, how flexible it needs to be... But thickness of the cable doesn't matter, as long as it's rated for the current and voltage you need and has enough conductors for your use case. And as long as it fits in whatever place you need it to fit in.

Comment: I also remember that having a longer extension cable means more potential voltage drops, does this apply to a 2m cable?

Comment: Should be fine if you stick within the ratings. You can calculate it, though, knowing the resistivity of copper and the length and cross-sectional area of the cable, as well as the current you're going to put through it.

Comment: I will use it up to 2.5kW, so a 250V/16A cable will be probably plenty enough (4kW), I will do the drop calculation later, thanks for that! One more thing, does the male and female schuko adapters also be rated for the given volts, or the cable is what is important - for example I am looking at a very thin male head on the cable, will that be lesser compared to a full thick shucko head?

Comment: Just check the ratings. I'm in the US, so I'm not familiar with Schuko plugs.